# What property of a function describes $f\left(f\left(f\left(\phi, x\right), y\right), z\right) == f\left(\phi, z\right)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, idempotents, programming

How would you describe a function that has the relationship $f\left(f\left(f\left(\phi, x\right), y\right), z\right) == f\left(\phi, z\right)$? given that $f\left(\phi, x\right)$ is idempotent (i.e., $f\left(f\left(\phi, x\right), x\right) == f\left(\phi, x\right)$?

Is this simply a property of idempotent functions?

An application of this function can be seen in a programming language where a method `object.SetProperty(x)` changes the state of the object. However, subsequent calls to `SetProperty()` overwrites the existing state. Thus the following are considered equivalent:

```
object = new Object;
object.SetProperty(x);
object.SetProperty(y);
object.SetProperty(z);
```

and

```
object = new Object;
object.SetProperty(z);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the property you are looking for is the following:
$$
f(f(\phi, x),y) = f(\phi,y) \text{ for all } x, y. \tag{1}
$$
If $f$ satisfies (1), then this both implies that $f$ is idempotent (by your definition) and also implies your condition, $f\left(f\left(f\left(\phi, x\right), y\right), z\right) = f\left(\phi, z\right)$.

So, I think (1) is the condition you want. I am not aware of a name for this property, except that it is similar to something called a "right zero" or "right-absorbing-element". So, I would suggest that if $f$ satisfies (1), then you could call $f$ **right-absorbing**. This is meant to refer to the fact that the right-most applied argument $y$ "absorbs" the other applied argument $x$.

> Is this simply a property of idempotent functions?

No, the property (1) is not true of *all* idempotent functions. For example, if $\phi$ is a set and $f(\phi, x)$ represents adding the element $x$ to $\phi$ (`phi.add(x)`), this is idempotent (because adding the same element twice to a set is the same as adding it once), but not right-absorbing (because adding $x$ and then adding $y$ isn't the same as just adding $y$).

Comment: Is it possible that $f$ could be idempotent and satisfy $f(f(f(\phi,x),y),z) = f(\phi, z)$ but not satisfy (1)?

Comment: @DarkMalthorp I think it is probably possible. So $f(f(f(\phi,x),y),z) = f(\phi,z)$ may be a weaker property than (1). The example given by the OP does satisfy (1), though.

Comment: Thanks for providing the example in which a function could be idempotent but not right-absorbing.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of a particular name for that property in *that* context,  however in probability there is the adjective **[memoryless](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness)** which corresponds to this idea.

See Poisson / Exponential variables,  as well as Markov processes.

Comment: Interesting idea! Although the underlying domain isn't related to Poisson/Markov processes, I think the term "memoryless" is adequate for the programming domain/context.